# Cool css effect onclick search input

Tags: javascript, css

There is this cool effect I came across online:

https://www.bnkle.com/

When you click the search bar a red line appears just under it making it look modern, sleek, etc.

How can I achieve this effect with pure css / js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```css
.box { transition: 1s; outline: none; border: 1px solid #ddd }
.box:focus { border-bottom-color: red; }
```

```html
<input class="box">
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much!